# OSGi application subsystem is ACTIVE, but its components are not

Tags: kotlin, osgi, apache-felix, aries

I have created an OSGi bundle (written in Kotlin) containing a very basic component, which I have annotated as `@Component(immediate = true)`. This bundle behaves as expected using Felix 6.0.3.

```kotlin
@Component(immediate = true)
class Bongo @Activate constructor(
    @Reference(service = LoggerFactory::class)
    private val logger: Logger
) {
    init {
        System.err.println("-------------- BONGO!")
        logger.info("Started {}", this::class.java)
    }

    @Activate
    fun doIt() {
        throw InternalError("BOOM!")
    }
}
```

I then zip this bundle up (with some others) and feed it into Apache Aries as a trivial application subsystem. I haven't created an explicit `SUBSYSTEM.MF` here because the default values *appear* to be what I want. Aries installs and starts my subsystem, and then reports that it is `ACTIVE`. I have even confirmed that a `BundleActivator` has been invoked correctly. However, I see no evidence that my `@Component` has been started. It looks like SCR has ignored it, which seems odd because I would have thought that I'd *need* SCR to run an application subsystem. (I have heard that Declarative Services have replaced `BundleActivator`...)

I have scoured the OSGi documentation and found no mention of needing to do anything with an OSGi subsystem other than "start" it, so I am baffled at how to proceed from here. Can anyone suggest anything I might have missed please?

For reference, these are the Felix / Aries bundles from my `bndrun` file:

```
    org.apache.aries.subsystem.api;version='[2.0.10,2.0.11)',\
    org.apache.aries.subsystem.core;version='[2.0.10,2.0.11)',\
    org.apache.aries.util;version='[1.1.1,1.1.2)',\
    org.apache.felix.bundlerepository;version='[2.0.10,2.0.11)',\
    org.apache.felix.configadmin;version='[1.9.18,1.9.19)',\
    org.apache.felix.coordinator;version='[1.0.2,1.0.3)',\
    org.apache.felix.log;version='[1.2.2,1.2.3)',\
    org.apache.felix.logback;version='[1.0.2,1.0.3)',\
    org.apache.felix.scr;version='[2.1.20,2.1.21)',\
    org.eclipse.equinox.region;version='[1.2.101,1.2.102)',\
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What programming language is this code sample written in?

Comment: I have since discovered that my components _are_ activated when I install my subsystem as a feature rather than an application. However, I am also trying to "sandbox" my subsystems from each other, and so the "import from the parent and export nothing" goal of an application seems to be a better fit.

Comment: This is Kotlin.

Comment: Okay, it's confusing because it looks like both the constructor and the `doIt` method are annotated with `@Activate`, which would be an error. However since I don't know Kotlin it's hard to tell if that's really true.

Comment: They both _are_ annotated with `@Activate`. The framework insists that the constructor is annotated because the component uses constructor injection. However, Felix doesn't object to the method being annotated too, and even executes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Neil Bartlett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318921/neil-bartlett), I now understand that each application subsystem would need to contain its own SCR bundle before Felix could find its components. Specifically:

> SCR is not just a dependency, it scans bundles for the `Service-Component` header. The Declarative Services specification does not describe any way for SCR to discover bundles inside a subsystem of the running framework, therefore your bundles will be invisible to it.

David Jencks has also elaborated specifically about the Felix SCR:

> IIRC you need to configure SCR with the `ds.global.extender`
> flag set to `true`, then the single SCR will find components everywhere.